# Intuition on One Class Support Vector Machines

Tags: machine-learning, svm, outliers, intuition

I am having trouble understanding how one-class SVMs work. They were introduced in a paper by Scholkopf and others (and can be found [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~williams/papers/P126.pdf)).

One-class SVMs perform "novelty detection", where a point is classified as either normal or abnormal, but you can only train your model on normal points.

In the paper linked above, the authors use SVMs for novelty detection by separating the training examples from the origin in feature space. They further claim that for certain values of parameters (specifically, their parameter $\nu$) their method is equivalent to a thresholded [Parzen Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) if the kernel function integrates to 1 over $\mathbb{R}$. Mathematically, this makes sense (equations 5 and 6 in the paper reduce to Parzen Windows for large values of $\nu$), however I am having trouble understanding this intuitively.

So here is my question: As I see it, separating points from the origin in feature space will necessarily mean that there exists some $n$-dimensional ball centered at the origin with radius $r$ such that for all points *outside* of this ball, they will be classified as ***normal***. Wouldn't this lead to a large portion of $\mathbb{R}^n$ being classified as normal? However, their paper claims that the solution has small volume.

Comment: The ball is not centered on the origin, the ball is centered somewhere and points *inside* the ball are normal. The usual difficult step is that finding a ball and finding a plane does not seem the same -but they are in the RBF kernel. In the RBF kernel all data points are on the surface of an infinite dimension ball of radius 1 (K(x,0)=1 for all x). Finding the svm ball on the surface of this radius 1 ball is the same as finding a plane - the intersection of the radius 1 ball with the svm ball

Comment: Thanks. I should have known that a hyperplane wouldn't necessarily be a "hyperplane" in the intuitive sense given a weird kernel.